# Encoding XAVC MXF with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode 4K video in XAVC MXF.
I have succeeded to encode in XDCAM MXF in 2K
But XAVC MXF seems to need additional parameter setting
Could you give me advice or sample code for setting
Format and codec parameter for XAVC.??

Comment: Could you post the command line(s) you've tried so far and the error log?

Comment: At first. Is it possible to make XAVC MXF with FFMPEG.?  It is my first check point..and I think FFMPEG seems not support XAVC MXF format